# Replace row in data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like that:

```
'data.frame':   3036 obs. of  751 variables:
 $ X           : chr  "01.01.2002" "02.01.2002" "03.01.2002" "04.01.2002" ...
 $ A: chr  "na" "na" "na" "na" ...
 $ B: chr  "na" "1,827437365" "0,833922973" "-0,838923572" ...
 $ C: chr  "na" "1,825300613" "0,813299479" "-0,866639008" ...
 $ D: chr  "na" "1,820482187" "0,821374034" "-0,875963104" ...
...
```

I have converted the `X` row into a date format.

```
dates <- as.Date(dataFrame$X, '%d.%m.%Y')
```

Now I want to replace this row. The thing is I cannot create a new dataframe because I after `D` there are coming over 1000 more rows...

What would be a possible way to do that easily?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is a very basic question answered on every introduction to `R` site you can find.  Please share some of your attempts and why they aren't working for you.  Also, `X` is a column, not a row...  That might help your google-fu.

Comment: First, `X` is not a row but a colum. Second, do you want to *replace* or *remove* it?

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Thx for your reply! I want to replace the column `X` with `dates`

Comment: you have numbers stored as charqcters. is that intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is simply:

```
dataFrame$X <- dates
```

if you you want to do is replace column `X` with `dates`. If you want to remove column `X`, simply do the following:

```
dataFrame$X <- NULL
```

(edited with more concise removal method provided by user @shujaa)

Comment: +1, Or, a more concise removal, `dataFrame$X <- NULL`.